# Rendering SVG shapes with crisp edges in IE9

Tags: svg, internet-explorer-9, antialiasing

IE9 appears not to honour the SVG `shape-rendering="crispEdges"` attribute.

Here's a sample SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="600" id="svgroot" version="1.1" width="800" x="0" y="0">
<line style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-opacity:1" y2="300" y1="300" x2="750" x1="50" shape-rendering="crispEdges" />
</svg>
```

It appears correctly under Firefox and Safari, however the line appears blured under IE9 and IE10 (Platform preview)

Is there some workaround to disable the anti-aliasing in IE9?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to just shift the line 0.5 "pixels" vertically instead of using shape-rendering. That way the line will look sharp in all non-IE browsers at least.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="600" width="800">
  <line style="stroke:#000" y2="300.5" y1="300.5" x2="750" x1="50" />
</svg>
```

Comment: I also figured out that a path has crisp edges when I shift _all_ moveTo commands by 0.5 pixels. `<path style="fill:none; stroke:#000;" d="M100.5,100.5l100,0,0,100,-100,0z">`.

Comment: @basecode: in such cases it's probably easier to tweak the viewBox, e.g viewBox="-0.5 -0.5 601 801" and leave the paths as they were originally.

Comment: Thanks, Erik. Why is this not default? I mean that solved all my problems. Crazy :)

Comment: Erik, not all my problems :) I can see a regression when I put the tweak to a svg-snippet like this: http://jsbin.com/aritem/edit. It's a path with a stroke width of "10". But when I change the stroke-width to "10.5" edges are crisp again. Even numbers should be shifted, odd numbers should remain the same. Is this a subpixel issue? Isn't that sth the UA should solve for us?

Comment: Erik, I overlooked that you also changed the size of the viewBox. I updated my example and tried to give some examples side by side. http://jsbin.com/aritem/4/edit

Comment: I can confirm this also does the trick in IE11 that otherwise suffers from the same antialiasing issues