# IE9 SVG blurry when resizing

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg, raphael

I have an incredibly odd case of IE9 displaying blurry graphics when the `<svg>` is floated next to another element.

Here's the simplest case I could come up with that is similar to our application:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<head>
    <meta content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <title>IE9 SVG Resize Issue</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {

    var i = 0;
    var increaseWidth = function() {
        var w = 500 + i++;
        window.resizeTo(w, 500);
        document.getElementById('currentWidth').innerHTML = w + 'px';
    };

    document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', increaseWidth);

    increaseWidth();
};
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div style="float: left; width: 20%">

Left
</div>

<div style="float: left; width: 80%">

  <svg width="200" height="200" version="1.1">

    <rect fill="#fff" stroke="#000" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="100" height="100" />

  </svg>

</div>


<span style="color: #999; display: block">NOTE: In IE9 you can only have one tab open to resize the window</span>
<button type="button" id="btn">Increase Width</button>
<span id="currentWidth" style="color: #666; font-size: 15pt"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

[Here's a gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1UOW.jpg) that shows resizing the window from `500px` to `507px`. You can see that the lines of the rectangle go from blurry to crisp when resizing by one pixel. The bug seems to occur when having the two columns with a percentage width. It can also happen when the `div` containing the `svg` overflows onto a new line (things become slightly blurry). FWIW, in the actual application we're using Raphael.js.

Is there a known issue associated with this and is there an easy fix to keep the lines crisp (with the usual offset by `0.5px` fix)?

Comment: I don't have IE9 handy to test, but adding `svg {display: block}` to your stylesheet might fix this.

Comment: @Duopixel - Thanks, but that didn't work.

Comment: I also can't test, but maybe using { shape-rendering: crispEdges; } as the css styling for the svg. It may be that the rectangle's stroke is straddling a pixel for certain dimensions, and IE may be anti-aliasing it funny.

Comment: @cmonkey - Nope :(. The [usual method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7282753/rendering-svg-shapes-with-crisp-edges-in-ie9) for crisp edges is to offset by 0.5px... but it *only* behaves odd in IE with this odd case.